# Angular js works on jsfiddle but not on my machine Strange ERROR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am a beginner when it comes to angular

so here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/knc6vrd9/1/

i have an simple app and as you can see i am just trying out the basics.

The example works fine on jsfiddle but when i run it on my machine i get a huge piece of error staring like this

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SimpleCont' is not a function, got undefined
```

And the **ng-repeat** doesnt show any output and the text input also doesnt work as well
i have run the page via a local wamp server as well and get the same result

Comment: you use the exact same code on your local machine?

Comment: issue in Your controller name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ommit creating a function, since angularjs is modular and provides you mechanism to create controllers, which can be used in applications.
So in your code, instead of:

```
function SimpleCont($scope){
    $scope.nameList=[
                        {firstname:'john'},
                        {firstname:'jane'}
                    ];
}
```

Create module and controller within it. First use module method from angular, which takes as first parameter name of module ( later to include in ng-app ) and as a second parameter dependency list, which in this situation is empty.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
```

Then invoke controller function on module. 
Module method always return itself, so you can add later another contorllers by using dot `.`.

```
 controller('SimpleCont', function(){
    this.nameList=[
                                {firstname:'john'},
                                {firstname:'jane'}
                            ];
    });
```

This is code instead of function, this code sets **module** and assign **controller** to it. 
In your application to use module and created controller within it, set ng-app properly. 
instead of:

```
<div ng-app>
```

use:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

Generally good to know how to create controllers and modules in angularjs for beggining, because later you can learn other curious things like **services**, **factories** and also get to know what is **$http** service and how to use it for making ajax calls. 
Also good to automate work thanks to **grunt**, **karma** and **yeoman**.

[Here](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/wrap-up) is good tutorial to start.

[Here](http://yeoman.io/learning/) is about yeoman a tool you can use to work with angular.